# Tkinter - multithreading inside for loops

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Let me describe the program first. The app is used to unzip a large (5 gb+) tar.gz file or extract some members from it based on input csv file (can be more than 20k rows). So, there are 2 file browsers on the GUI and button Start.

The problem is that during the execution the window is freezing and does not respond. I have read about multithreading, but when I tried it, the program had a lot of errors (e.g. 21417 arguments in functions, thread was not main etc.).

Here is my code:

```
class App(Tk.ttk):

    def get_folder(num):
        ....
    #returns array of members' names
    def processCSV(self, delta_file):    
        ....

    def unzip_changes(self, delta_file_arr, inputARES):
        row            = 22 #used for GUI

        #debug
        self.debug_output("Unzip changes", row, "Start: ")

        tarfile_ARES = tarfile.open(inputARES)
        time_not_found = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        file_not_found = open(self.logs_path + time_not_found + '.log', 'w')

        #counters for progress bar
        self.counter    = 0
        self.maxcount   = 22000

        #extract
        for name in delta_file_arr:
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.counter +=1
            try:
                member      = tarfile_ARES.getmember(name)
                member.name = os.path.basename(member.name)
                result      = re.search("(.*).xml", member.name)
                res         = result.group(1)
                r           = res[:-1]
                num         = int(r)
                tarfile_ARES.extract(member, self.get_folder(num))
            except:
                result         = re.search("./VYSTUP/DATA/(.*).xml", name)
                res            = result.group(1)
                file_not_found.write(res + "\n")
                continue
        #after extract, closing
        self.pb.stop()
        showinfo("Success", message="The execution was successfully completed.")
        file_not_found.close()
        self.destroy()

    def unzip_tar_gz(self, ARES_tar_gz):
        row             = 22 #used for GUI
        self.debug_output("Unzip", row, "Start: ")
        tarfile_ARES    = tarfile.open(ARES_tar_gz)
        
        #counters for progress bar
        self.counter    = 0
        self.maxcount   = 1200000
        
        #extract
        for member in tarfile_ARES.getmembers():
            self.update_idletasks()
            member.name = os.path.basename(member.name)
            result      = re.search("(.*).xml", member.name)
            res         = result.group(1)
            r           = res[:-1]
            num         = int(r)
            tarfile_ARES.extract(member, self.get_folder(num))
            self.counter+=1
            
            #debug
            if self.counter%100000 == 0:
                row += 1
                self.debug_output("extract 100k", row, "Success")

        #after extract, closing
        showinfo("Success", message="The execution was successfully completed.")
        self.pb.stop()
        self.destroy()

    #browse file, input
    def filebrowser(self, input, type):
        ...

    #starts extracting based on input arguments
    def process(self, inputARES, inputChanges):
        if inputARES == "":
                showinfo("No file", message = "Please, choose ARES file")
        elif inputChanges == "":   
            answer = askyesno(title='confirmation',
                             message='The process will take approx. 12 hours. Are you sure?')
            if answer:
                self.pb.grid(column=3, row=15, sticky=W, padx=(60,0))
                self.pb.start()
                self.start_button.config(text="Running")
                self.update_idletasks()
                t1   = threading.Thread(target = self.unzip_changes, args = (inputARES))
                t1.start()
                t1.join()
                self.unzip_tar_gz(inputARES)
        else:
            answer = askyesno(title='confirmation', message='The process will take approx. 30 minutes. Are you sure?')
            if answer:   
                self.pb.grid(column=3, row=15, sticky=W, padx=(60,0))
                self.pb.start()
                self.start_button.config(text="Running")
                self.update_idletasks()
                t2   = threading.Thread(target = self.processCSV, args = (inputChanges))
                t2.start()
                t2.join()
                delta_file_arr = self.processCSV(inputChanges)
                t3   = threading.Thread(target = self.unzip_changes, args=(delta_file_arr))
                t3.start()
                t3.join()
                self.unzip_changes(delta_file_arr, inputARES)
# GUI
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #window settings
        self.title("Unzip tar.gz Files")
        self.geometry("1920x1080")
        self.config(bg="#E88D14")
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(self, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #styling
        s_frame   = ttk.Style()
        s_frame.configure('TFrame', background='#E88D14')
        s_br_buttons = ttk.Style()
        s_br_buttons.configure('Browse.TButton', background = '#D85604', foreground = 'black')

        #text fields
        s_labels = ttk.Style()
        s_labels.configure('TLabel', foreground = 'white', background = '#E88D14')
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Entering just ARES file means processing the whole tar.gz file", 
                  font=("Arial",10)).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W, padx=(15,0))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="(est. time ~12 hours)", 
                  font=("Arial",8)).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W, padx=(15,0))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Entering both file names means changes processing", 
                  font=("Arial",10)).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W, padx=(15,0), pady=(5,0))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="(est. time ~30 min)", 
                  font=("Arial",8)).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W, padx=(15,0))
        
        #input ARES file
        ares               = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Enter ARES File: ")
        ares.grid(column=3, row=5, sticky=W, padx=(15,0), pady=(15,0))
        inputAres          = ttk.Entry(mainframe, background="white", width=60)
        inputAres.grid(column=3, row=6, sticky=W, padx=(15,0), pady=(0,10))
        browse_ARES_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse",command= lambda: self.filebrowser(inputAres, "tar.gz"), style='Browse.TButton')
        browse_ARES_button.grid(column=4, row=6, sticky=E, padx=10)
    
        #input delta file
        changes      = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Enter Changes File: ")
        changes.grid(column=3, row=7, sticky=W, padx=(15,0))
        inputChanges = ttk.Entry(mainframe, background="white", width=60)
        inputChanges.grid(column=3, row=8, sticky=W, padx=(15,0))
        browse_Changes_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse", command= lambda: self.filebrowser(inputChanges, "7z"), style='Browse.TButton')
        browse_Changes_button.grid(column=4, row=8, sticky=E, padx=10)

        # folders
        self.main_folder             = r'path'
        self.delta_file_extract_path = self.main_folder + 'delta_file/'
        self.logs_path               = self.main_folder + 'logs/'

        #progress bar
        self.counter  = IntVar()
        self.maxcount = IntVar()
        self.pb       = ttk.Progressbar(mainframe, mode='determinate',orient='horizontal',
                                        length=200,variable=self.counter.get(),maximum=self.maxcount.get())

        #used in debugs
        self.label    = ttk.Label(mainframe,text= "")

        #start processing
        self.start_button    = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Start", 
                                command=lambda: self.process(inputAres.get(),inputChanges.get()))
        self.start_button.grid(column=4, row=14, sticky=S, pady=(20,0), ipady=15, ipadx=15)
        self.mainloop()
```

Could you, please, help me with multithreading? How can I avoid these errors?

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I see in your implementation is the args you provide to [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> args is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to ().

In your case, you do not provide a tuple, but only surround the variable with parentheses:

```
args=(inputARES)
```

"Bare" parentheses are used for grouping only, making them redundant in this case. To create a single-element-tuple, you need to add a comma:

```
args=(inputARES,)
```

However, even if you make the threading work this way, it will not solve your unresponsiveness issues. The app will still wait on the completion of the thread on the `t1.join()` command, making the app freeze for the user.

You need to further implement a function which periodically polls the thread for completion, while keeping the app responsive during the polling pauses.

I would suggest [a tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-thread/) to get further insights into that approach.